# Execute remote commands as root using Python and paramiko

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

Currently I'm working on a Python script to run embed shell scripts, the OS contain *root* and *normal_user*.

The problem is, when I try to switch from *normal_user* to *root*, using a single command in one line.

I have to only modify the code and nothing like `visudo` to achieve this and use `su` only without giving the *normal_user* any rights outside the coding .

How can I achieve this?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('172.16.x.x', username='my_name', password='my_password')

***stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('switch to root user && execute a commands as root')***


stdin.flush()
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the OS environment has `sudo` command installed and `normal_user` is allowed to [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to root without a password:

```
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo -i -H -- echo $USER ; echo $USER')
```

Options -i simulators root login (prepares `.profile`, etc. environment variables), option -H sets the `$HOME` directory the same as the root. These may or may not be necessary depending on your use case.

`echo $USER` example shows that you are executing that command as root (it should return $USER = root).

As a security measurement you can set the `normal_user` to have sudo rights only if the user logs in with a correct SSH key.

http://www.evans.io/posts/ssh-agent-for-sudo-authentication/ (complex)

Comment: My suggestion would be that in that case install sudo. Because if you have root access you should be able ti install whatever software you want. I am not sure if su has non-interactive way of executing commands as root, but it is long time ago I used it last time as sudo is practically everywhere now.

Comment: Thank you very much Mikko for your kind help, there is a policy in the company to not give a sudo to the Normal_user i really don't know what to do.

Comment: If normal_user has no su/sudo root access and you login as normal_use your business case is impossible. Sorry, I cannot help with social problems within your organization :)